# The same UTF8 code looks different in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

My code looks like this:

```
NSString *replace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\2013 %@",tmp];
```

It will display within the `UITextView`. The question is when `tmp` is English, it shows everything normally. But when I change `tmp` into Chinese, the `en dash` changed like this:

[image]

How do I sort out this problem?

Comment: It's probably a different font, which has a different glyph for the same unicode code point.

Answer (score 0):

That's a normal behavior. dash in Chinese and dash in En was encoded differently in UTF8. Actually, comma(and some other pubctations) also looks different in En and chinese. Have a try:)